# SSIS Script Component stripping underscores from column names

Tags: ssis, script-component

SSIS Script component strip's under scores from columnnames.

Example :  ColumnName :  Customer_ID

in Script components it looks as

```
public override void SourceIn_ProcessInputRow(SourceInBuffer Row)
{
     Row.CustomerID
}
```

How can i get Column Name with underscore, as I have to pass column name to other .dll which does error logging and needs correct column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem this morning, I didn't really need the underscores so accepted it after a little complaining. Perhaps after your script task you could drop in a Derived Column transform or Copy Column transform into the dataflow and set the name to exactly what you need.